# rewriting .htaccess to hide real page path

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to hide real page path using `RewriteCond` inside `.htaccess`

As i wanted to give my user download link of a perticular file. Suppose

```
www.mnc.com/myBook.pdf

www.mnc.com/youBook.pdf
```

Now this myBook and youBook is inside of `public/pdf`directory. As you can see that i tried to hide the directory from Url.

Now how i set the .htaccess rule so that when a user tried to access `www.mnc.com/myBook.pdf` it will automatically set the url path to `www.mnc.com/pdf/myBook.pdf` so that directory could be hide in browser path.

Comment: Hope my post will help you out..

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for rewrite I assume and assuming you are using rules in root dir try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.pdf$ /mnc/pdf/$1.pdf [L]
```

Comment: Right now i'm trying in Localhost.So when i tried to access 
`localhost/mnc/public/youBook.pdf` inisde Browser..
I see `NotFoundHttpException` Error

Comment: Well try in mnc directory.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your anser.

Comment: What is the error are you getting you can check here http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ the rule is working fine. it should work fine in mnc folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple one.

For redirection of such requests like

`localhost/mnc/public/youBook.pdf` to

`localhost/mnc/public/pdf/youBook.pdf`

> **1.** if `REQUEST_URI` ends with `.pdf`
>
> **2.** Flags `L,NC,END` is `last rewrite`,`non case sensitive` and `for ending further redirection` respectively.

**Note:** If you don't use `END` flag it will case loop of rewriting.

**.htaccess code:** [You can try this here](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.pdf$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/([\w]+\.pdf)$ $1/pdf/$2 [L,NC,END]
```

Comment: Right now i'm trying in Localhost.So when i tried to access `localhost/mnc/public/youBook.pdf` inisde Browser.. I see `NotFoundHttpException` Error

Comment: Can you please give me an example what you are trying and which url you are hitting and what is your expected output url?

Comment: @User57 Lets say if you access `localhost/mnc/public/youBook.pdf` then what will be the url you want to execute ?

Comment: `localhost/mnc/public/pdf/youBook.pdf` I want to execute